# Using nn.ModuleList over Python list dramatically slows down training

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm training a very simple model that takes the number of hidden layers as a parameter. I originally stored these hidden layers in a vanilla python list `[]`, however when converting this list to a `nn.ModuleList`, training slows down dramatically by **at least one order of magnitude**!

**AdderNet**

```
class AdderNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_hidden, hidden_width):
        super(AdderNet, self).__init__()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

        self.hiddenLayers = []
        self.inputLayer = nn.Linear(2, hidden_width)
        self.outputLayer = nn.Linear(hidden_width, 1)

        for i in range(num_hidden):
            self.hiddenLayers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_width, hidden_width))

        self.hiddenLayers = nn.ModuleList(self.hiddenLayers)  # <--- causes DRAMATIC slowdown!

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.inputLayer(x)
        out = self.relu(out)

        for layer in self.hiddenLayers:
            out = layer(out)
            out = self.relu(out)

        return self.outputLayer(out)
```

**Training**

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        out = model.forward(data[i].x)
        loss = lossFunction(out, data[i].y)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because when using a normal python list, the parameters are not added to the model's parameter list, but when using a ModuleList, they are. So, in the original scenario, you were never actually training the hidden layers, which is why it was faster. (Print out model.parameters() in each case and see what happens!)

Comment: Really? So this means that during training that ONLY the input and output layer were being trained??

Comment: Good point. One   ** has ** to use ModuleList in order to make the parameters trainable. However this is very slow.. Is there a way to speed up ModuleList?